# Remove the multiple object from nested object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, javascript-objects

How can we remove the multiple objects from nested object array? I tried below code using filter but that is returning undefined. Please suggest a better way of doing it.

```js
let removedIds = [1, 2]

let gridData = [{
    Id: 1,
    name: "ABC",
    class: "XYZ",
    college: "AB",
    collectionRows: [{
            Id: 1,
            name: "ABC",
            class: "XYZ",
            college: "AB",
        },
        {
            Id: 2,
            name: "ABC",
            class: "XYZ",
            college: "AB",
        },
        {
            Id: 3,
            name: "ABC",
            class: "XYZ",
            college: "AB",
        }
    ]
}];

let newData = gridData.map((row) => {
    {
        row.collectionRows = row.collectionRows.filter((subRow) => {
            return !removedIds.includes(subRow.Id);
        });
    }
    return row;
});

console.log(newData, 'newData');
```

Comment: Also `.filter()` returns a new array with the filter predicate applied. You have to assign that back to `row.collectionRows`.

Comment: Updated the code, that is also not working.

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: @cmgchess The current output is expected after your edit

Comment: then you have solved the problem? i didn't change the code

Comment: Thanks, I realized.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.

Live Demo **:**

```js
let removedIds = [1, 2]

let gridData = [{
    Id: 1,
    name: "ABC",
    class: "XYZ",
    college: "AB",
    collectionRows: [{
            Id: 1,
            name: "ABC",
            class: "XYZ",
            college: "AB",
        },
        {
            Id: 2,
            name: "ABC",
            class: "XYZ",
            college: "AB",
        },
        {
            Id: 3,
            name: "ABC",
            class: "XYZ",
            college: "AB",
        }
    ]
}];

const res = gridData.map(obj => {
    obj.collectionRows = obj.collectionRows.filter(({ Id }) => !removedIds.includes(Id));
  return obj;
});

console.log(res);
```